# prove the set $C = \{(e^{-x}\cos(x), e^{-x}\sin(x)):x\geq0\} \cup \{(x,0): 0 \leq x \leq 1\}$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I want to prove the set $C = \{(e^{-x}\cos(x), e^{-x}\sin(x)):x\geq0\} \cup \{(x,0): 0 \leq x \leq 1\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Here is my attempt: I tried letting $C_1 = \{(e^{-x}\cos(x), e^{-x}\sin(x)):x\geq0\} \cup \{(0,0)\}$ and $C_2 = \{(x,0):0\leq x\leq1\}$; then it suffices to show $C_1$ and $C_2$ are closed since $C = C_1 \cup C_2$.

Now $C_2$ is closed since if $(a_n)$ is a convergent sequence (converging to the limit $l=(l_1,l_2)$) of elements in $C_2$, then each $a_n = (b_n, 0)$ for $b_n \in [0, 1]$.  It follows that $(0)$ converges to $l_2$ (so $l_2 = 0$) and $(b_n)$ converges to $l_1$ - since $[0, 1]$ is closed and $(b_n)$ is a convergent sequence of elements in $[0, 1]$, then it follows that $l_1$ is in $[0, 1]$ and so $l \in C_2$.

However, I'm having a hard time showing $C_1$ is closed.  Intuitively, the components of $(e^{-x}\cos(x), e^{-x}\sin(x))$ are continuous and as $x$ approaches infinity, this approaches $(0, 0)$.  Not sure how to translate this into a proof.

Comment: For $C_2$ you can also write it as $[0,1] \times \{0\}$, a product of closed sets, hence closed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x_n,y_n)$ be a sequence in $C_1$ converging to $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$. Only finitely many terms of this sequence can be equal to $(0,0)$. In the contrary case we can write $(x_n,y_n)=(e^{-t_n} \cos t_n, e^{-t_n} \sin t_n)$ for all $n$ sufficiently large. But then $ x^{2}+y^{2}= \lim (x_n^{2}+y_n^{2})=\lim e^{-2t_n}$ which shows that $t_n \to -\frac 1 2  \ln (x^{2}+y^{2})$ . This gives $(x,y)=(e^{-t}\cos t, e^{-t} \sin t)$ where $t=-\frac1 2 \ln (x^{2}+y^{2})$.

Comment: $(0,0)\in C_1$ by definition

Comment: Please read the definition of $C_1.$

Comment: @zhw. Thanks for the comment. I have corrected my answer.